# Leio o arquivo txt, mas mostra em branco

Tags: c++

Quero ler uma tabela verdade de um arquivo txt
porém não ta mostrando nada do arquivo, nem os numeros da tabela, nem outro caractere qualquer que eu tenha colocado para testar

```
#include<iostream>
#include<STDIO.H>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int valor;

    FILE *arquivo;

    arquivo =  fopen("tbV.txt","rt");
   
    fscanf(arquivo, "%d", &valor);
    fprintf ("%d", valor);

   if(arquivo==NULL){
    cout<<"Não foi possivel abrir o arquivo"<<endl;

   }

   fclose(arquivo);
}
```

Comment: Poste pelo menos uma linha de exemplo de seu arquivo. Seria conveniente você testar se conseguiu abrir o arquivo **antes** de utiliza-lo e não testar depois de tentar utiliza-lo.

Comment: Poste o arquivo de teste e o resultado esperado. Escreveu um programa em C na verdade...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valide se o arquivo foi aberto e use [caminhos absolutos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caminho_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)#:%7E:text=Um%20caminho%20absoluto%20ou%20completo,do%20diret%C3%B3rio%20de%20trabalho%20atual.) ou relativos ao diretório de execução.

```
 if ((arquivo = fopen("C:\\program.txt","r")) == NULL){
       printf("Erro ao abrir arquivo");
       exit(1);
 }
```